# How to test event listeners defined in SpringBootApplication

Tags: spring, unit-testing, spring-boot

Trying to write test of SpringBootApplication:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes=Application.class)
@TestPropertySource(locations="classpath:application-test.properties")
public class PropertiesConverterTest { ...
```

Application class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@PropertySource("classpath:/application.properties")
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication application = new SpringApplication(Application.class);
        application.addListeners(new MyListener1());
        application.addListeners(new MyListener2());
        application.run();
    }
}
```

But it seems to be that no one of the listeners is been started.
How should that type of function be tested?
Is it possible at all?

If to be more specific, I want to test properties modification feature implemented in one of the listeners (ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent listener).
It actually works, I just want to write a simple test.
My idea is to load ApplicationContext and just try to read modified properties using `@Value` annotation or `environment.getProperty("my.property.name")`

Comment: So basically you want to test Spring Boot... You don't trust that the events get fired?

Comment: By all indications, they are not activated
In addition I ran the test in debug mode with break points. Stops were not even in the main method of the Application.class

Comment: But if I run the app not in the test environment, all of my listeners do their work.

Comment: Ofcourse they don't run, you are running the test not the main method. However I'm questioning if you should test this. You are more or less testing spring boot. If you want to test your listener write a simpel unit test not an integration test like this.

Comment: Ok! How to do that? Btw, It was my question

Comment: So why is Application.class even mentioned in annotation parameters if it is not being used anywhere? and judging by https://spring.io/blog/2016/04/15/testing-improvements-in-spring-boot-1-4 , I should be getting "all the spring boot goodness", so where is it?

Comment: It will use the annotations it will NOT invoke the main method so any configuration done in there will not be applied when running a test. However as stated do you want to test Spring Boot or your listener. I suspect the later, just create an instance in a unit test, mock the dependencies and assert the expected outcome.

Comment: i just check and answered a similar questions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52085355/how-to-register-a-applicationenvironmentpreparedevent-in-spring-test/52094909#52094909

Comment: @borino big 10x!